# Declaring pointers to function returning arrays is actually legal?

Tags: c, arrays, language-lawyer, c11

At least by the C11 standard and from what I've read.

The only place where return type is not allowed to be an array type is in the section of function definitions (at $6.9.1.3):

> The return type of a function shall be void or a complete object type
>   other than array type.

At function calls ($6.5.2.2.1) it states this:

> The expression that denotes the called function shall have type
>   pointer to function returning void or **returning a complete object type
>   other than an array type**.

Which means that something like this would be expected:

```
int (*pf1)()[4]; //legal?

pf1(); //error calling a function which return array
```

What I mean is that from how I understand the standard only **defining a function returning arrays is illegal and not defining a pointer to function returning arrays**. Prove me wrong if you can. Also if I'm wrong I would be happy if you explain me why is this sentence in the standard then?

Although clang doesn't seems to think that way and will rise an error in the above code stating that 'function cannot return array type 'int [4]''. But is this really a function (and not rather a pointer to one)?

**EDIT**:

OK - I was answered by citation of the standard paper that 'function declarators' can't have a return-type of array. However if we use a typedef name instead to declare a pointer to function returning arrays - would this be legal? -

```
typedef int arr_t[4];

arr_t (*pf1)(void);
```

Although I personally think that this case is also covered by the answers because the type-name defined by a 'typedef' is the same as one explicitly defined.

Comment: You can't define pointers to objects that can't exist.  You can't create a function that returns an array of 4 integers; therefore, you can't declare a pointer to such a function either.

Comment: `int func()[4]` is not valid C, there is no such thing as a function returning an array so this code is just gibberish. So I don't see how `int (*func)()[4]` would suddenly become valid C. It is not a pointer to a function returning an array, because there is no such thing, it is merely gibberish.

Comment: A less questionable example would be: `typedef int arr_t[4];`and then `arr_t (*pf1)(void);`. Which won't compile either.

Comment: Post a question please? Or maybe I should edit this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence that you found is indeed only about function definitions, not about declarations. However, you missed another constraint:

> **6.7.5.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1 A function declarator shall not specify a return type that is a function type or an array type.

> Also if I'm wrong I would be happy if you explain me why is this sentence in the standard then?

There needs to be an additional requirement that a called function returns a complete object type because a function declaration is allowed to declare it as returning an incomplete type:

```
struct S;
struct S f(); /* valid */
void g() { f(); } /* invalid */
struct S { int i; };
void h() { f(); } /* valid */
```

It's not about arrays. The wording about "other than an array type" is just to make sure arrays don't accidentally become allowed by a mistake in the wording.

Comment: Why is then this rule which doesn't allow calling function pointers which return arrays?

Comment: @FISOCPP I was just adding that. It isn't so much about requiring functions being called to not return arrays, it's about requiring functions being called to return completed object types.

Comment: So then an undefined structure is an array type? What?

Comment: @FISOCPP No, in my example, `struct S` is an incomplete object type in the declaration of `f` and in the first call of `f`. That can't work for that call. The rule is there to require a complete object type. However, if the rule simply said that a function being called must return `void` or a complete object type, that could be read as implicitly allowing returning, say, `int[4]`, since that too would be a complete object type. So the rule says "a complete object type other than an array type". It's not really about arrays.

Comment: Yeah but as we can't define or even declare a function type returning an array then I think this statement is either a mistake or a leftover of something different(maybe the committee was planning to allow pointer to functions returning arrays).

Comment: @FISOCPP No, it's not a mistake, it makes perfect sense. I already gave you a very specific example of a source file that is invalid because of that one sentence, that would have otherwise been valid, that cannot possibly work on common implementations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99611/discussion-between-fisocpp-and-hvd).

Answer (score 0):

> Declaring pointers to function returning arrays is actually legal?

No. Its not legal. You will get a compile time error. A function can't return an array.

For the time being, if `int (*pf1)()[4];` is valid anyhow, then the function call

```
pf1();
```

doesn't make any sense. `pf1` is not pointing to any function.