# Casting to pointer to function returning array - is it allowed?

Tags: c, function, casting, language-lawyer, c11

This question is somehow linked with this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579977/declaring-pointers-to-function-returning-arrays-is-actually-legal).

My last revision shows that the paragraph stating that arrays returning functions can't be called may have some actual usage. Remember this one ($6.5.2.2.1):

> The expression that denotes the called function shall have type
>   pointer to function returning void or returning a complete object type
>   other than an array type.

The limitations of functions returning arrays concerns only function 'declarators' and 'definitions'. However if we look at the cast operator, there is no rule disallowing 'function-types' which return arrays to be used as a 'type-name' in it.

Look at '$6.5.4.2':

> 6.5.4 Cast operators
>
> **Syntax**
>
> cast-expression:
>
> ```
>  unary-expression 
>
>  ( type-name ) cast-expression
> ```
>
> Constraints
>
> Unless the type name specifies a void type, **the type name shall
>   specify atomic, qualified, or unqualified scalar type**, and the operand
>   shall have scalar type.

Now if we look at '$6.2.5.21':

> 21 **Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar
>   types**. Array and structure types are collectively called aggregate
>   types.

And then at '$6.2.5.20':

> — A function type describes a function with specified return type. A
>   function type is characterized by its return type and the number and
>   types of its parameters. A function type is said to be derived from
>   its return type, and if its return type is T , the function type is
>   sometimes called ‘‘function returning T ’’. The construction of a
>   function type from a return type is called ‘‘function type
>   derivation’’.
>
> — A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object
>   type, called the referenced type. A pointer type describes an object
>   whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type.
>   A pointer type derived from the referenced type T is sometimes called
>   ‘‘pointer to T ’’. The construction of a pointer type from a
>   referenced type is called ‘‘pointer type derivation’’. A pointer type
>   is a complete object type.

As I see there is no constraint which forbids something like this:

```
void *ptr;

(int (*)()[4])ptr;
```

Or is it?

Comment: You can't return "bare" arrays from functions, so why would you expect to be able to have a pointer to such a function? No such function can exist.

Comment: gcc complains and throws an error `main.c:11:5: error: type name declared as function returning an array                                                                                                           
     (int (*)()[4])ptr;              `

Comment: @unwind  So what - this question is labeled - 'language-lawyer'.

Comment: @Dom Well that's kinda weird because at '$6.7.7' (Type names) there is no such restriction.

Comment: Why would it allow you to cast to return arrays if in C you can't return arrays?

Comment: @unwind: I wouldn't *expect* to be able to have such a pointer, but the constraints on functions returning arrays are only given for function calls and function declarators. As far as I can tell, the type-name in a cast operator is neither.

Comment: @Dom: "Why" is not the question -- but the reason is probably that it's just an oversight.

Answer (score 6):

*I'm less sure of this than I was. See Jens Gustedt's comment and my incomplete analysis at the bottom of this answer.*

It's commonly said that C does not permit functions that return arrays, but the only constraints that enforce this restriction are (quoting [the N1570 C11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)):

6.5.2.2p1 (function calls):

> The expression that denotes the called function shall have type
>   pointer to function returning **`void`** or returning a complete
>   object type other than an array type.

and 6.7.6.3p1 (function declarators):

> A function declarator shall not specify a return type that is a
>   function type or an array type.

(I searched for the word "Constraints" in section 6 of the standard. I don't think I missed anything. If I did, I'm confident someone will point it out.)

The type-name in a cast operator is not part of a function call and is not a declarator, so neither constraint applies.

As a result, I believe that this program:

```
int main(void) {
    if (0) {
        void *ptr;
        (int (*)()[4])ptr;
    }
}
```

is strictly conforming and must be accepted by a conforming implementation. (I added the `if (0)` to avoid any issues regarding the run-time semantics of the conversion; the behavior of converting a `void*` to a function pointer is undefined by omission.)

This means, I think, that a type-name denoting a function returning an array, or a function returning a function, is permitted as long as it's not used in a function call or function declarator. For example, it could be used in a generic selection, in a `sizeof` or `_Alignof` expression, and in several other contexts.

This is, of course, not useful, and it's probably just an oversight on the part of the committee.

I note that gcc (version 5.3.0 with `-std=c11 -pedantic`) rejects the type-name with a message:

```
type name declared as function returning an array
```

This seems like a reasonable diagnostic, but strictly speaking it's non-conforming since no actual constraint is violated.

Veering off the topic of the question for a moment, gcc also complains:

```
 warning: ISO C forbids conversion of object pointer to function pointer type [-Wpedantic]
```

which is not strictly correct. ISO C doesn't *forbid* such a conversion; it merely does not define its behavior.

**UPDATE :**

Jens Gustedt's comment suggests that a *type-name* is a *declarator*, and that therefore a type-name referring to a function returning an array violates the constraint in 6.7.6.3p1. Let's take a look at that, following the grammar in N1570 Annex A and referring to the section numbers there.

The constraint refers to a "function declarator". Since there's no grammar production called *function-declarator*, it must be referring to a *declarator* that refers to a function type. If there's no declarator, then the constraint is not violated.

The type-name `int (*)()[4]`, if it's valid, refers to a pointer to function returning an array of 4 `int`s (thanks to `cdecl`).

*My analysis is incomplete. I'll have to come back to this later.*

Comment: I don't think the case of defining a 'typedef' of such type is allowed as function declarators shall not specify a return type that is an array. Unless function declarators are only such things that define or declare functions.

Comment: @FISOCPP: That's exactly it. A `typedef` is not a function declarator.

Comment: No I'm convinced that you can't define a 'typedef' name which have a type (or sub-type) function returning an array. If you want we can discuss it [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100691/can-a-typedef-define-a-function-returning-array-or-pointer-to-one).

Comment: @FISOCPP: I believe you're right. As you say, `typedef` is syntactically a storage class specifier. It requires a declarator.

Comment: " the behavior of converting a pointer function to void* is undefined by omission"  - actually your code converts the `void *` to function pointer.  But you could avoid this issue by casting some other function pointer (e.g. `(int (*)()[4])main`)

Comment: IMHO "forbid" is a reasonable description for undefined behaviour . Compilers can always offer extensions whether or not it is a constraint violation.

Comment: @M.M: You're right, and I've updated my answer accordingly. I didn't want to change the code too  much from what was in the question. As for "forbid" being an apt word, I disagree, but there's not much point in debating the meaning of the word "forbid".

Comment: I see. So there are really two language-lawyer issues here (the compiler's treatment of object-pointer to function-pointer conversion;  and the conversion to this particular function-pointer type)

Comment: Did you look up the syntax table for *type-name*? I think a function type in there is very well a declarator. So this construct is indeed a constraint violation.

Comment: I'm looking at it now. You may be right, but I'm not yet convinced.

Comment: @JensGustedt No - it's not - it's rather *abstract-declarator* (at $6.7.7).